Can unbelievers change their attitude towards God in Hell?
A popular (Eastern Orthodox) view of afterlife proclaims that God's presence is akin to torture for an unbeliever (Hell) and akin to bliss for a believer (Heaven). It claims that Heaven and Hell are different responses to presence of God, rather than 2 different places.
This brings me to my question.
From the Eastern Orthodox perspective can unbelievers change their attitude towards God in the afterlife, and thus turn their Hell into Heaven?

There is a teaching by Origen a Church Father called Apokatastasis, and this teaching laid down the possibility of damned souls escaping hell. This is hard to contemplate, but if we read Hans Balthasar writings on "We dare to hope, hell is empty.", then we can see that this scenario will happen during the Eucharistic Era at the New Paradise,wherein Daily Masses are being offered for 1K years to empty purgatory, and when purgatory is emptied, the darkness of hell are now expose to the light. Light vs. darkness, John1:5 shines, and so, the damned souls will finally be expose to the light.Ave!

Between us and you there is a great gulf fixed, that they that would pass from hence to you may not be able, and that none may cross over from thence to us. Luke 16:26.

@NigelJ You cited the parable of the Rich Man and Lazarus. Where is the Rich Man in that particular passage, purgatory like or real hell of the damned? Was the Rich Man eternally condemned by God for simply not sharing food with the beggar? Are we not all guilty of this type sins?

@jongricafort The rich man is disembodied but his brethren are still alive on earth. Therefore the general resurrection has not taken place and the lake of fire is not yet kindled. He awaits his bodily resurrection but nonetheless is aware of his dreadful condition. Nothing can change his present conditon or his future fate. The time to repent is past.

@NigelJ Im simply asking if the Rich Man was eternally condemned to real hell, or was he in the place of purging?

To be clear, is this question about what the Eastern Orthodox churches would say?

I am answering from the perspective of EO, however this is actually way more complicated then anyone here seems to realize. To properly answer we must understand the difficulty of "Origen" within the "not" saints. Because he did teach something about this...

See also Universalism in the Orthodox Church?, Heaven/Paradise/Sheol, Hell/Hades/The Lake of Fire, and What is the scriptural basis for the idea that salvation can still be obtained after death?

The long answer, with context, history, etc... and at the bottom the short answer.
I would say that the view of "Heaven" and "Hell" as states of being and not "places" is a core position of the limited understanding of the afterlife that Eastern Orthodoxy claims we have.

You are asking about something called "Universal Salvation" (Apokatastasis). That is all will be saved eventually.
Your version is basically, "in the afterlife can we change our minds?" So if in the afterlife we repent, would we be able to change our perspective and see the light of God as love instead of burning fire?

On Universal Salvation

Apokatatasis and the 5th Ecumenical Council (and Origen one who taught it)
The first obvious step to figuring out things properly from the Orthodox Perspective is the Fifth Ecumenical Council in 553AD. Where the general subject of Apokatastasis was not condemned as heresy. But many versions of it seemed to be heresy, but then there is Origen, the "not saint" who taught other saints.
Things get really tricky now. This council both condemns and does not condemn Origen. Specifically the synod only anathematized one person—Theodore of Mopsuestia (Ep. 51). As well as a general condemnation of a group of people...

5th Ecumenical Council, Canon 11:
If anyone does not anathematize Arius, Eunomius, Macedonius, Apollinarius, Nestorius, Eutyches and Origen, as well as their heretical books, and also all other heretics who have already been condemned and anathematized by the holy, catholic and apostolic church and by the four holy synods which have already been mentioned, and also all those who have thought or now think in the same way as the aforesaid heretics and who persist in their error even to death: let him be anathema.

The canon does not specify which of Origen’s teachings are condemned, nor do the acts record any discussion of them by the council fathers. Origen is simply included among the anathematized. This is where things get tricky. The others in the list were denounced, directly or indirectly, by previous ecumenical councils and their heresies were well known; but those councils had never condemned Origen. Which teachings of Origen, therefore, did the bishops of the Fifth Council believe to be antithetical to the apostolic faith and to which synod or synods were they appealing?

We do not know—neither the canons nor the acts of the council tell us. This point needs to be stressed. We may not assume that because the council fathers condemned Origen by name they specifically intended to condemn his teaching on apokatastasis. The establish­ment of conciliar dogma requires more than guesswork and conjectural inference. -Fr Aidan Kimel


Let me say to any who may consider it an important matter to be assured whether Origen was, or was not condemned, by some ancient Synod, two things—(1) That if it could be ever so conclusively proved that “Origen was condemned” by the Fifth Council, this would afford no evidence whatever that he was condemned on account of his doctrine of restitution, since he held a great many other doctrines much more open to blame than this one. And then (2) Supposing Origen’s doctrine of restitution had been “by itself condemned,” this would be no condemnation of the doctrine of restitution, as now held, e.g. by Mr. Jukes or by Dr Farrar [two 19th century exponents of universal salvation]; since their two doctrines of restitution are in many important points essentially different.  -F. Nutcombe Oxenham, 19th century Roman Catholic theologian and historian

So, even though that's a catholic he is correct in pointing out that condemning this specific teaching of Origen is itself a problem. The reason is that after canon 11 denounced him, a lot of other other people started to denounce Origen as well. (After all, they must or be anathema as well)... and they metaphorically "threw his books at him" going after him for every little thing possible.

“Jerome, Theophilus, and Epiphanius literally scrape together every possible charge against Origen, but never allude to his teaching of the larger hope as heretical.” (Thomas Allin, Christ Triumphant (1905), p. 178.)

So that is interesting, they would have included it easily with the backing of the 5th Ecumenical council canon 11 if it had been heresy. So it must not have been one of the problem teachings.
It is also annoyingly unusual that the canons of the 5th Council do not name "which heresies", they usually did. However we do have various "anti-origen" canons. For the sake of brevity none of them condemn Apokatatasis, the closest one is Canon 1 which condemns the "pre-existence of souls and the monstrous restoration" (That is to say, the implication of the pre-existence of souls) this is mirrored within the Orthodox Liturgy Synodikon which is read on the sunday of Orthodoxy by every Orthodox church every year.
What both of those are condemning is an entire system of thought, a form of universalism that includes the beliefs of the preexistence of souls, the temporality of heaven, etc. This pre-existence is something that Origen did teach. You can read about this heretical reasoning some in (Journey Back to God: Origen on the Problem of Evil by Mark S.M. Scott) or other texts by Origen.

Apokatatasis and the issue of the Consensus of the Church Fathers
This is shorter, a common argument is that a lot of church fathers taught "eternal damnation" however...  far more Church Fathers than is usually recognized believed in universal salvation, many having very big names, such as Sts. Gregory of Nyssa or John Cassian (source: Ilaria L. E. Ramelli's various works on early church fathers)
The short version is... a lot of the "big names" that are the foundations of doctrine and teaching, wisdom and understanding believed in universal salvation.

Apokatatasis and Scripture
But what about scripture? It literally says "eternal damnation" or "everlasting fire" and many other colorful descriptions. Äh... This is a full book of information at this point. (If you want to delve deeper see here for more quotes from church fathers on the subject or here for a book on universal salvation that gets into the detail of words being different)
Hart discusses [within the book I linked above] in detail the logic of the scriptures, how words generally translated as eternal, etc. are much broader or different in their meaning, and how these other meanings actually make more sense in the context of any given verse

With regards to scripture, Hart points out that the word aionios (άΐδιος), so often translated into English to mean eternal or forever, is far more plastic in its meaning than many have realized. It could mean an indeterminable amount of time. Hart goes on to list a number of Church Fathers, bishops, and even Neoplatonic philosophers who understood the word in this latter sense up through the fourteenth century. Likewise, the Greek phrase εἰς τοὺς αἰῶνας τῶν αἰώνων (eis toùs aionas ton aiṓnōn) literally means “unto the ages of ages,” not forever. For Hart then, the usages of these phrases indicate not “how long, but rather of when, or what frame of reality – what realm, that is, within or beyond history” (pp. 123-127). Hart also dismisses the interpretation of Matthew 25:46 as a proclamation of eternal damnation, saying, “We might even find some support for the purgatorial view of the Gehenna from the Greek of Matthew 25:46 (the supposedly conclusive verse on the side of the infernalist christians), where the word used for the ‘punishment’ of the last day is κόλασις,  kolasis – which most properly refers to remedial chastisement – rather than τιμωρία, timoria – which most properly refers to retributive justice” (pp. 116).

So in modern english our understanding seems to drastically vary from what the Ancient Church Fathers understood by literally the same verses. (Another fun example of this would be the understanding the lake of fire as the fires of the purifying love of God, instead of the "burning vengeance of God" after all God is Love)

This is not an exhaustive list of things, but it certainly shows that Orthodox Christians are able to be universalist or infernalist, neither is considered heresy (unless you add something that makes them monstrous like "pre-existence" or such)
Short Answer

Your understanding of Orthodox Heaven and Hell as states of being is accurate.


Universal Salvation is not heresy. But infernalists are also not heretics.
Many church fathers believed in universal salvation, even of Satan.
Scripture when understood properly in the original language, context, etc has a deeper meaning and points towards a Loving God whose creation was good, and will be restored after the 2nd coming of Christ. (And literally everything is part of creation except God)

What does this mean? The actual answer to exactly what happens in the afterlife is "We don't know", but I do trust the church fathers and the councils. If Satan might eventually be saved... so can everyone else. But ultimately we cannot know... and unlike catholics or protestants who need to often "nail down" (lol) a specific answer or explanation, the orthodox church does not. We don't understand many things like how the bread and wine become meat and blood. We know that it does. Similarly we trust in God to save us. I'm clearly a universalist, as thoughts of eternal suffering from a loving God is not viewing the scriptures through the lens of Love.

we can know because eternal means forever and Jesus said eternal fires prepared for the devil and his angels, I cannot believe you just said you do not know in your answer.

The word apokatastasis occurs once in scripture, used by Peter, Acts 3:21, and does not bear, either in etymology (apo/kata/stasis - a superlative down stabilising) or in context, your own, preferred, meaning. And he shall send Jesus Christ, which before was preached unto you: 21Whom the heaven must receive until the times of restitution of all things, which God hath spoken by the mouth of all his holy prophets since the world began. This answer has no basis in the Greek language.

@NigelJ The use of the word "Apokatatasis" as understood by the modern era Eastern Orthodox church is basically the concept that "all will be saved eventually" please see here "https://orthodoxwiki.org/Apocatastasis" and "https://orthochristian.com/99054.html" which both say the same thing as I did. For a Heumentical debate about the word "Apokatastasis" in Acts 3:21 please open a new question in Heumentics as it seems really weird here. Also, I did not claim to make a "greek language" answer. I only stated the fact that it is called Apokatatasis within the Orthodox Church.

Oof, that pun
